# Knox does not work after Hive service restart

Tags: hive, oracle-sqldeveloper, metastore, apache-knox

I use SQL Developer and some third party jar files for accessing Hive.

When ever there is a Hive service restart - My connection object wont let me connect to Hive after the restart. My admin team need to restart the metastore too. And then few more config changes, admin team does - and then I need to remove the cacerts file, add certificates to cacerts again using Apache knox.

Have any of you faced similar problems and managed to fixed it ?

Thanks
LNC

Comment: what's the exact exception/error you are getting?

Comment: In SQL Developer - It gives "Error while connecting to database" and some vendor code. Admin team restarted metastore - so I was not able to capture the exact error.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late response here. This sounds like an issue that has since been resolved with HiveServer2 using a random key for signing the cookie that is used to optimize authentication of each http request for a given session. When HS2 is restarted a new key is created and the Knox server continues to send the previously cached cookie which was signed with the previous random key. There should be no reason to mess with cacerts and the like. A simple - yet annoying - restart of Knox should suffice. You may also turn off cookie based authentication but that will degrade performance.

Comment: Thanks Imccay !! This time - HDP admin provided a set of libraries for jdbc connectivity and new bash & cmd executable for adding  ca certs. I believe that took care of this issue. Anyways thanks very much for your response !!